# Insert query check if record exists - If not, Insert it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a mysql table `ip_list`...

```
+----+---------------+
| id |    ip_addr    |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | 192.168.100.1 |
|  2 | 192.168.100.2 |
|  3 | 192.168.100.3 |
|  4 | 192.168.100.4 |
|  5 | 192.168.100.5 |
+----+---------------+
```

I want to add only that records which are not in `ip_addr` column.
**For ex**

I have following records to add in `ip_addr` table

```
192.168.100.6
192.168.100.10
192.168.100.11
192.168.100.1   //already in column
192.168.100.12
```

I don't want to add `192.168.100.1`, because it is already in column.

So, is it possible that `INSERT` query first check the records then insert it?

Currently, I am doing this with.. first I `SELECT` the records then match it and then `INSERT` it.

but, I want to do with only one query.

Comment: is the record from the other table/.

Comment: You could add a unique index to the ip column and then you're left with `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY` or `INSERT IGNORE`

Comment: make `ip_addr` as `unique` field

Comment: can't you simply add unique index to **ip_addr**

Comment: @all I know about `unique` key

Comment: @JW can I do this without `unique key`?

Comment: adding unique constraint on the column would be a better idea, in my own opinion.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar yah thats what I want, let me check its working or not

Comment: How could you do this without having to make **ip_addr** column unique?
@casperOne: This is NOT a duplicate question. What you linked to requires the use of a _primary_ key. THIS question does not.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use below query. Here it will insert the ip_address when it is not present in your table.

```
INSERT INTO ip_list (ip_addr)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT '192.168.100.1') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT ip_addr FROM ip_list WHERE ip_addr='192.168.100.1'
);
```

Comment: Ekach number yogesh bhau.

Comment: +1 upvote for your answer, thanks :)

Comment: I've wanted to do this for about 10 years but never thought to Google it. Just accepted doing 2 queries - select then insert. this is superb!

Comment: Super method. Is there a way of extending this to multiple values at one go ? For examples check if 192.168.100.1 and 192.168.100.2 exist else insert both.

Answer (score 9):

You should add a UNIQUE key on `ip_addr` and then use `INSERT IGNORE`.

Maybe this helps if you haven't heard of `UNIQUE` yet: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-unique.htm

Comment: +1 upvote for your answer, thanks

Answer (score 5):

Try MySQL [INSERT IGNORE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) statement.

Comment: +1 upvote for your answer, thanks

Comment: this is better option ,because we does not need more computation.

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE INTO tableName`

Answer (score 4):

if I were you, I enforce a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column,

```
ALTER TABLE ip_list ADD CONSTRAINT IP_Unique UNIQUE(ip_addr)
```

Comment: +1 upvote for your answer, thanks

Answer (score 4):

you can do that with [Insert...on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

OR

alternatively you can also be use [Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html)

Comment: +1 upvote for your answer, thanks

Comment: Replace, what a great invention! Thanks