# Ignore duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am importing some data from a csv file into MySQL and trying to ignore duplicate rows.

```
mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO products (parent_product_url, child_product_url, swatch) VALUES ('".$row[0]."', '".$row[1]."', '".$row[2]."')");
```

My csv file.

```
polo.htm,red.htm,red.jpg
polo.htm,green.htm,green.jpg
round-neck.htm,green.htm,green.jpg
```

Now if I run below csv file it should ignore first three rows as they already exists in the table. It should insert only fourth row.

```
polo.htm,red.htm,red.jpg
polo.htm,green.htm,green.jpg
round-neck.htm,green.htm,green.jpg
v-neck.htm,red.htm,red.jpg
```

Comment: What is the primary key on products and do you have any unique key also?

Comment: ID is the primary key and it has auto increment, I do not have unique key but I think we can take "child_product_url" as unique.

Comment: Okay, in that case, MySQL is behaving correctly. `insert ignore` will throw warning and not insert a record if that record violates primary or unique key. Since combination of those 3 fields does not violate any constraints, MySQL happily inserts those data over and over again. To prevent that from happening, you could create unique index on parent_product_url (if it makes sense to do so).

Comment: I think I got you. So are you suggesting to alter database structure?

Comment: Oh no. Your database structure is fine. Just like Gordon mentioned, to prevent duplicate values for combination of the 3 fields, you would have to add a unique composite index using the 3 columns. In my answer I have added some examples for reference.

Comment: I changed child_product_url to Unique and it works but when I insert a new row with different parent_product_url and add existing child_product_url it does not update.

Comment: Your goal is to ensure that parent_product_url + child_product_url + swatch combination must be unique, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Great. In that case, create a unique index on those 3 columns. `create unique index uk_products_parenturl_childurl_swatch on products(parent_product_url, child_product_url, swatch);`. Before you make the index, make sure you don't have duplicate data in the table already.

Comment: Actually I do not have the flexibility to add a fourth column. Can I still achieve it?

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please re-phrase the question? You want to add a 4th column to the table or to the index or to the CSV?

Comment: Yes. The create unique index suggested in both answered and previous comment will allow you to do what you intend to do

Comment: I assume you meant a new column in the database as unique indexes correct?

Comment: I meant doing this: `create unique index uk_products_parenturl_childurl_swatch on products(parent_product_url, child_product_url, swatch);`  Did you execute this statement and try the inserts again?

Comment: I updated my code to http://pastebin.com/NkL9ijGM and nothing happens. looks like it just executes the second query normally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92332/discussion-between-zedfoxus-and-azee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved with the help of this Answer -> [Insert query check if record exists - If not, Insert it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898599/insert-query-check-if-record-exists-if-not-insert-it#answer-15898661)

Below is my updated query

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO products (parent_product_url, child_product_url, swatch)
             SELECT * FROM (SELECT '".$row[0]."', '".$row[1]."', '".$row[2]."') AS tmp
             WHERE NOT EXISTS (
             SELECT * FROM products WHERE parent_product_url='".$row[0]."' AND child_product_url='".$row[1]."' AND swatch='".$row[2]."'
             );");
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `on duplicate key update` because `insert ignore` ignores *all* errors, not just duplication errors.

Regardless of which you use, your problem is probably the lack of unique constraint/index.

You don't specify what you mean by "duplicate".  Assuming you mean all the columns:

```
create unique index unq_products_3 on products(parent_product_url, child_product_url, swatch);
```

Note: there is a maximum length to the keys used for indexes, depending on the storage engine.  If your columns are too long, you may need to think about other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Records are inserted again when you re-execute insert statements because the inserts are not violating any unique or primary key index. Therefore MySQL doesn't have anything to ignore.

```
create table products (
  parent_product_url varchar(100), 
  child_product_url varchar(100), 
  swatch varchar(100)
);

-- this will enter both records
insert ignore into products values ('polo.htm', 'red.htm', 'red.jpg');
insert ignore into products values ('polo.htm', 'green.htm', 'green.jpg');

-- this will enter both records **AGAIN**
insert ignore into products values ('polo.htm', 'red.htm', 'red.jpg');
insert ignore into products values ('polo.htm', 'green.htm', 'green.jpg');
```

Now let's add uniqueness to parent_product_url and try again:

```
truncate table products;
create unique index uk_products_parent_product_url on products(parent_product_url);
insert ignore into products values ('polo.htm', 'red.htm', 'red.jpg');
insert ignore into products values ('polo.htm', 'green.htm', 'green.jpg');
```

This will enter only the first record. 2nd record will be ignored and a warning will be thrown. No error will be thrown.

If you desire to have a combination of the 3 columns to be unique, then you would do this (This is what Gordon Linoff has mentioned also...I am just adding more context):

```
alter table products drop key uk_products_parent_product_url;
create unique index uk_products_parenturl_childurl_swatch on 
  products(parent_product_url, child_product_url, swatch);
insert ignore into products values ('polo.htm', 'red.htm', 'red.jpg');
insert ignore into products values ('polo.htm', 'green.htm', 'green.jpg');
```

Now you will see only two records inserted even when you re-execute the same 2 insert statements many times.

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that
>   duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table
>   causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may
>   generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.