# Stopping insertion to the database when the data already exists with Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I'd like to know how to prevent an insert into a database when the data is already existing inside it. And how to make an onclick window with a message that alerts the user that the data they're inserting is already inside the database.

How I get inputs from my view goes a little bit like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Controller/insertdata">    
    <h3>Select Course Code:</h3>
    <select id="employeeid" name="empid">
        <option value="" selected="selected">---Select Course Code---</option>
        <?php foreach ($e_id as $row4): ?>
        <option label="<?php echo $row4['EmpID']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row4['EmpID']; ?>" <?php echo set_select('course', $row4['EmpID'], False); ?>> <?php echo $row4['EmpID'] ; ?> </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" id="submite_id">
```

It takes data from the database into the select tag. My database has Employee ID, Employee name, Dept. code, and assignment.

Here's my Controller:

```
public function insertdata() {
    $this->model->setdata();
    $data['results'] = $this->model->emp_all();
    $this->load->view('edit_view', $data);
}
```

It inserts the data into the database and redirects the user to a view.

And finally here's how I insert it into the database in my Model:

```
public function setData(){
    $f1 = $_POST['empid'];
    $f2 = $_POST['empname'];
    $f3 = $_POST['deptcode'];
    $f4 = $_POST['assignment'];

$this->db->query("INSERT INTO employeeDB VALUES('$f1', '$f2', '$f3', '$f4')");
}
```

The catch is that the users should not be able to assign an employee id, and name to a duplicate assignment on the same department.

Any reply, comment, and insight will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Before insert do a select  query with where clause if it's returns any row it's duplicate otherwise you can insert it .

Comment: How can I check if it has a duplicate? Inside an if statement?

Comment: just do this select query before insert  `select * from table name where empid=value and empname=value and deptcode=value` if it's return any row it's duplicate otherwise it's not duplicate .

Comment: Just put a `'` in any of the values that should prevent an insert ;p

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898599/insert-query-check-if-record-exists-if-not-insert-it

Comment: ^Thanks for that! I didn't know there was a "where not" query

Comment: Is this correct?
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO databasename VALUES('$f1', '$f2', '$f3', '$f4') WHERE NOT EXISTS (Select * from databasename where databasename.empid = '$f1' AND databasename.empname = '$f2' AND databasename.deptcode = '$f3')");

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSERT IGNORE INTO` query. It won't insert record in table if data is already exists.

Please have look [here](http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html%5C).
Hope this will help.

Comment: Apparently it only works if you have a primary or unique key. But my empdb has around 2 primary keys(empid and deptcode) so I dunno if that'll work

Answer (score 0):

You can use Codeingiter `form_validation` library.

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('empid', 'Employee ID', 'required|trim|employeeDB.empid');
```

Where the last Parameter `employeeDB.empid` is used as `table_name.column_name`.  So your Controller will be as below.

```
public function insertdata() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('empid', 'Employee ID', 'required|trim|employeeDB.empid');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        // Form Validation Failed. 
        $this->load->view('myform');
    } else {
        // Form Validation Passed. 
        $this->model->setData();
        $data['results'] = $this->model->emp_all();
        $this->load->view('edit_view', $data);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will try this ASAP!

Comment: tried it, I can't seem to insert into the database anymore even the non-duplicate ones

Comment: Just check your code if data insertion. Check if setData() function is being called in your model. There might be a small systex error or something.

Comment: I have just copied your previous code and wrapped it inside conditional statement. It should work fine if it was working previously.

Answer (score 0):

in sql server use can use NOTEXIST for protect to duplicate insertion